# jQuery : Change query string parameter and reload the page on button click

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a URL like this

http://localhost:60041/AnnualAppraisal/PotentialQuotient.aspx?EmpCode=677593&FYDetailID=1045&FYID=36&FYName=2017-18&Grade=F2&EmpReviewTypeId=73&FEnabled=70&PageType=MGR

I have a save button and I save the data in db through ajax call.

After save I changed the `FEnabled` to 71 in my database and how can I change the query string parameter in the URL, as I do only ajax post and not redirecting to any page.

I see a lot of answer in sw but they only have one query string parameter.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex `/(?<=FEnabled=)(.*)(?=\&)/` with [.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and [.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

```js
var url = 'http://localhost:60041/AnnualAppraisal/PotentialQuotient.aspx?EmpCode=677593&FYDetailID=1045&FYID=36&FYName=2017-18&Grade=F2&EmpReviewTypeId=73&FEnabled=70&PageType=MGR';

var regex = /(?<=FEnabled=)(.*)(?=\&)/;
var number = parseInt(url.match(regex)[0]);
console.log('This is the old number: ' + number);
var url = url.replace(regex, number+1);
console.log('This is the new url: ' + url);
```

Comment: This is what I wanted. Thanks for the help :) :)

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using this function I did long time ago in javascript. It should work:

```
function replaceURLParameter(key, value) {
    // value = value.split(' ').join('-'); //replaces spaces with dashes
    var parameter = key + "=" + value;
    var url = window.location.href;
    var urlparts = url.split('?');
    var finalUrl = false;

    if (urlparts.length >= 2) {
        /*url has parameters*/
        var pars = urlparts[1].split(/[&;]/g);
        var exists = false;
        pars.forEach(function (element, index) {
            var k = element.split('=')[0];
            var v = element.split('=')[1];
            if (k == key) {
                exists = true;
                if (!value)
                    pars.splice(index, 1);
                else
                    pars[index] = parameter;
            }
        });

        if (exists) {
            finalUrl = urlparts[0] + "?";
            pars.forEach(function (elem, index) {
                finalUrl += elem;
                if (index != pars.length)
                    finalUrl += "&";
            });
        }

        if (!exists) {
            /* The parameter to add doesnt exists but we have others. */
            finalUrl = url + '&' + parameter;
            finalUrl = setPage(1, finalUrl);
        }
    }

    if (urlparts.length < 2) {
        /*url without parameters*/
        finalUrl = url + "?" + parameter;
    }

    return finalUrl;
}
```

the call in your example should be `replaceURLParameter('FEnabled',71)` and it should return the full url (string) with the new parameter in the query string